# How can I extract a date substring from a date+time string in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm a newbie in Coldfusion. I'm trying to change a string that looks like "Jun 11, 2014, 8:50 PM" to "Jun 11, 2014".  I tried to use

```
<cfset album[currentrow]['date'] = ListGetAt(album[currentrow]['date'], 2, ",")>
```

It gives me 2014.  If I change 2 to 1, I get Jun 11.  Can someone please give me some advice on if there's a method to extra everything before the second ","?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the string is always formed of three comma-separated parts, and the date is always the first two, then you can do this:

```
dateTimeString = "Jun 2, 2014, 6:20 PM";
dateString = listDeleteAt(dateTimeString, 3);
date = parseDateTime(dateString);
dateFormattedForOutput = dateFormat(date, "mmm d, yyyy");
```

Note that you should only ever use `dateFormattedForOutput` for output; if you're storing the date or manipulating it, use `date`.

Comment: Or you could do that... didn't think about Deleting an item, but thats smart, especially if you're not keeping the string/list afterwards.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the first two steps are all that's required.

Comment: It's unlikely that simply displaying the value is the entire requirement, so converting it all the way to a date object is sensible. From there, one *uses* the date object for [whatever], including formatting for output. I realise that the values for the second and fourth step are the same, but that's coincidence as much as anything else. I did kinda touch on this in the last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Messing with strings isn't tough, but since you are working with a date, lets use the Date Functions.
If you have a string, the best thing to do is convert it into a Date Object, using

```
<cfset myDate = ParseDateTime(string)>
```

Then once it is a Date Object, you can do whatever you want with it. Use Dateformat to manipulate it as needed.

```
<cfoutput>#dateformat(myDate, "mmm dd, yyyy")#</cfoutput>
```

[ParseDateTime documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7843.html)

[DateFormat documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff4.html)

Edit - Using Strings instead.

You can use LEFT to get the left piece of the string. To know how many characters your want, you need to find the location of the second "," comma. Assuming the format is consistent, the first comma should be no more than 8 characters in, so we use FIND to look for "," in the string, starting at position 8.

```
<cfset theLoc = find(",", album[currentrow]['date'], 8) >
```

Then we use the left function to get the characters, but we do not want the comma, so we take 1 off of it.

```
<cfset theDate = left( album[currentrow]['date'], theLoc- 1 )>
<cfoutput>#theDate#</cfoutput>
```

You can do it all inline, but its a little messier

```
<cfset theDate = left( album[currentrow]['date'], find(",", album[currentrow]['date'], 8)- 1 )>
```

Comment: Hi. I just tried ParseDateTime(string) and got an error: "Jun 2, 2014, 6:20 PM is an invalid date or time string." Do you have any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had used it with that type of Date String format before, but I guess its not one of the format it recognizes. I guess we could resort to string manipulation... I'll post a couple of options, hold on.

Comment: Ok, edit made. Hope that helps. There are lots of ways to skin a cat, but when working with dates as strings, try and convert them, because then its much easier to do anything you want with them. In this case, string manipulation isn't bad, left is simple, that's what I used. You could use GetListAt 1 and GetListAt2 and trim and combine them too... up to you. I think Left is pretty readable... and that's important long term.